# How to fix underline text hover going to far in responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-website

I am trying to make a responsive navbar that allows the navbar to collapse and open on mobile view, however when I try to open the navbar in mobile view and hover over the different links, my animation that puts a line under the text when hovering seems to be too long and doesn't stick the same length as the text. However works fine on normal desktop view.

[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Bj8.png)

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector("#menu-icon");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle("bx-x");
    navbar.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.nav-link {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-link::before {
  transition: 300ms;
  height: 3px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-link-ltr::before {
  width: 0%;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-link-ltr:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}


.lyrics {
  padding-top: 5%;
}



.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  position: sticky; top:0;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 35px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation:
    typing 2s steps(17),
    cursor .4s step-end infinite alternate;
}

/* cursor blinking effect */
@keyframes cursor {
  50% { border-color: transparent; }
}

/* Typewriter effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .header {
    padding: 1.25rem 4%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display:block;
  }

  .navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5rem 4%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar.active {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Matt</a>

        <i class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></i>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Contact</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Projects</a>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <p class="text">Hello, Matt Here.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="lyrics">
        <h3>Molly - Playboi Carti.</h3>
        <p>
            Look at these diamonds, they shinin' (Yeah)<br>
            Look at these bitches, they lyin' (Yeah)<br>
            Baby, these diamonds not Johnny (Yeah)<br>
            I just called up Avianne (Yeah)<br>
            I don't got no stylist (Yeah)<br>
            All my planes are privates<br>
            Perkys on the privates<br>
            We don't fuck with molly<br>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your mobile view, you have set `width: 100%;` in the `.navbar` class and changed the `a` links from `display: inline;` (default) to `display: block;`. As a result, the links now also take up the 100% width of your navigation bar. The easiest and fastest solution is to add the `width` property to your links and set it to `fit-content`. Finally, to center the text again you also need to change the left/right `margin` of the links from `0` to `auto`.

So change this part:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        margin: 1.5rem 0;
    }
}
```

To this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar a {
        display: block;
        margin: 1.5rem auto;
        width: fit-content;
    }
}
```

Finally, here is a working snippet:

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector("#menu-icon");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle("bx-x");
    navbar.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background: blue;
}

.nav-link {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-link::before {
  transition: 300ms;
  height: 3px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-link-ltr::before {
  width: 0%;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-link-ltr:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}


.lyrics {
  padding-top: 5%;
}



.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  position: sticky; top:0;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 35px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation:
    typing 2s steps(17),
    cursor .4s step-end infinite alternate;
}

/* cursor blinking effect */
@keyframes cursor {
  50% { border-color: transparent; }
}

/* Typewriter effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 36px;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .header {
    padding: 1.25rem 4%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display:block;
  }

  .navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5rem 4%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar.active {
    display: block;
  }

  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    margin: 1.5rem auto;
    width: fit-content;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Matt</a>

        <i class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-icon"></i>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Contact</a>
            <a class="nav-link nav-link-ltr" href="#">Projects</a>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <p class="text">Hello, Matt Here.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="lyrics">
        <h3>Molly - Playboi Carti.</h3>
        <p>
            Look at these diamonds, they shinin' (Yeah)<br>
            Look at these bitches, they lyin' (Yeah)<br>
            Baby, these diamonds not Johnny (Yeah)<br>
            I just called up Avianne (Yeah)<br>
            I don't got no stylist (Yeah)<br>
            All my planes are privates<br>
            Perkys on the privates<br>
            We don't fuck with molly<br>
        </p>
    </div>
```